# Vimeo plugin for NativeScript

Tags: ios, nativescript, vimeo-ios, vimeo-android, angular2-nativescript

Is anyone aware of a plugin for NativeScript which allows you to play videos from Vimeo in iOS and Android, and would work with loading the src of the videos from an Angular 2 variable?

[Brad Martin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1893557/brad-martin) has written a cool [videoplayer plugin](https://github.com/bradmartin/nativescript-videoplayer) for NativeScript, which can play remote and local videos. Videos hosted on Vimeo, Youtube etc require using their custom SDKs. I asked Brad [a question](https://github.com/bradmartin/nativescript-videoplayer/issues/18) on this issue and he suggested a plugin was the best way forward.

1) Before I reinvent the wheel, is anyone working on this already / would be interested in collaborating?

2) Second question: if I go down the route of writing the plugin, can any Native app developer-Vimeo experts recommend the best SDKs for iOS and Android I should use to base my plugin on?

Comment: did you find anything?

Comment: No sorry, I ended up using React Native instead

Comment: that's some real bad news...

Answer (score 0):

Stack Overflow is probably not the best place for this type of question;

1. To see if any plugins already exist; you should check http://plugins.nativescript.rocks
2. To See if any plugins are already in development I would do a google search on NativeScript and Vimeo, and maybe even a search against Github.
3. To find out about collaborating on a plugin I would probably query the plugins and general channel on the NativeScript slack.